# How to get view content from a resource file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In an ASP.NET MVC project, I've been asked to devise a way to embed certain controllers and its corresponding views in a resources file in a library project; the idea is to have a library that provides these controllers and its views in order to not allow the developer to modify or disable them.

In the case of controllers without views (for example, `ApiController`s), it's a simple task: add the relevant WebApi NuGet packages to the library project, add a controller with the desired methods tot he library project and add this library as a dependency to the ASP.NET WebApi project; the controllers will appear automatically. But when it's a regular MVC `Controller`, I need to consider views, and every renderer assumes that the view's contents are in a file somewhere.

What I want to build is a way to load a traditional Razor view from a resources file instead of from a file on disk; let's say my library project has a `Views.resx` file and inside there's a regular text resource called `HealthStats` which is a regular Razor view's content in a text file. Inside the same library there's a `Stats` controller with a `HealthStats` action that returns the `HealthStats` view. The idea is that if I add the library to an ASP.NET project as a reference, the `Stats` controller is available and when calling the `HealthStats` action, it returns the view as expected.

I read about the `IView` and `IViewEngine`interfaces, but I'm not sure that's what I have to implement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot see any difference between ApiController and Controller, they both pass the Model the View. But if you want to render your View from a text file, you can look at https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working.

For those interested, do the following (I'm assuming you have a regular ASP.NET MVC project -**A** from now on- and a separate class library project in the same solution -let's call it **B**-):

- Create your resource file in B (I used the name *Views.resx* in the example).
- Add your views to that resource file as regular text files. Be aware that you won't have Intellisense. You can create the views in A and copy/paste them into B for easier development. Also, you should pick a naming strategy for the resources you create there (you'll need it when getting the views' content; in this example, I used `CONTROLLER_VIEW` as naming pattern). Another consideration: special characters in the views yo add to the resource file will NOT be correctly shown unless you replace them with the corresponding HTML entities.
- Implement the following classes in B:

```
public class ResourceVirtualFile : VirtualFile
{
    private byte[] _content;

    public byte[] Content
    {
        get { return _content; }
    }

    public ResourceVirtualFile(string virtualPath, byte[] content)
        : base(virtualPath)
    {
        _content = content;
    }

    public override Stream Open()
    {
        return new MemoryStream(_content);
    }
}
```

```
public class ResourceVirtualPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _resource_entries;
    private static Regex _virtual_path_regex;

    static ResourceVirtualPathProvider()
    {
        _resource_entries = Views
            .ResourceManager
            .GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true, true)
            .OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
            .ToDictionary(d => d.Key as string, d => d.Value as string);
        _virtual_path_regex = new Regex(@"~{0,1}\/Views\/(?'controller'[\w]+)\/(?'view'[\w]+)\.cshtml$");
    }

    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
    {
        var view_exists = CheckViewExistsInResource(virtualPath);
        if (view_exists)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.FileExists(virtualPath);
    }

    public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
    {
        var view_content = GetViewFromResource(virtualPath);
        if (view_content == null)
        {
            return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
        }
        else
        {
            return new ResourceVirtualFile(virtualPath, view_content);
        }
    }

    public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart)
    {
        var view_content = GetViewFromResource(virtualPath);
        if (view_content != null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return Previous.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
        }
    }

    private string ProcessVirtualPath(string virtualPath)
    {
        var match = _virtual_path_regex.Match(virtualPath);
        if (!match.Success)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var resource_name = string.Format(
            "{0}_{1}",
            match.Groups["controller"].Value,
            match.Groups["view"].Value);
        return resource_name;
    }

    private bool CheckViewExistsInResource(string virtualPath)
    {
        var resource_name = ProcessVirtualPath(virtualPath);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resource_name))
        {
            return false;
        }
        var contains_view = _resource_entries.ContainsKey(resource_name);
        return contains_view;
    }

    private byte[] GetViewFromResource(string virtualPath)
    {
        var resource_name = ProcessVirtualPath(virtualPath);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resource_name))
        {
            return null;
        }
        var contains_view = _resource_entries.ContainsKey(resource_name);
        if (!contains_view)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var view_content = Views.ResourceManager.GetString(resource_name);
        var view_bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(view_content);
        return view_bytes;
    }
}
```

These classes allow you to implement a path provider that translates MVC's path requests into names you can get from B's resource file. In case `ResourceVirtualPathProvider` cannot get the views for you, it'll defer to A's regular path provider.

- Finally, register this new path provider in A's `Global.asax`, in the `Application_Start` method

```
HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new ResourceVirtualPathProvider());
```

And you're done. Create as many views as you wish in B; as long as you respect the naming pattern, the views will be found and shown.